# How to write query to count the foreign key in yii using CDbCriteria?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I have tables `Ads` with column `AdsId`,`ClientId` and table `Assigned` . Assigned has `AdsId` as foreign key. I want to count the number of `AdsId` in Assigned for given `ClientId`. I have the following query which works but I am not sure if its the best way. How can I run the same query in yii? Hope I made my question clear.

```
SELECT A. * , (
SELECT COUNT( B.AdsId ) 
FROM Assigned AS B
WHERE B.AdsId = A.AdsId
AND A.ClientId =1
)
FROM Ads AS A
WHERE A.ClientId =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: you need stat relations see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare a relation in your model relations function

```
public function relations(){
     return array(
        ...
       'AdsIdCount'=> array(self::STAT,'Ads','AdsId'),
       //'VarName'=>array('RelationType', 'ClassName', 'ForeignKey', ...additional options)

     );
}
```

then in your in returned activeRecord results you can just call this count like this

```
$result = Assigned::model()->find($criteria); 

$result->adsIdCount ; // do logic here
```

or

```
$results = Assigned::model()->findAll($criteria); 
foreach ($results as $result){
    $result->adsIdCount ; // do logic here
}
```

see STAT relation for more details on how this works http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query

Comment: Thanks a lot, Learnt a new thing today :)